# When would the absence of "break" at the end of a while loop lead to infinite loops?

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I created a silly function to see if a string contains digits or not.

```
def check_digit_placement(w):
    if w.isalpha():
        return True
    else:
        i=0
        while True:
            if w[i].isdigit():
                return True    #Would the absence of "break" here lead to an infinite while loop?
            else:
                return False    #And here too.

            i+=1

          if i>len(w):
              break
```

The function works, but I am still a bit concerned, as indicated in the comments above: without a proper break, would the loop get stuck at some i, returning "True" or "False" infinitely many times? And if it would, why then does the function seem to work? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a syntax error (`break`'s can't be outside `while` loop). Also, the program will always come out after it scans the first digit since you have an `if-else` -- one of them will be always true. Can you explain your requirement with examples?

Comment: Both branches of the `if` statement have a `return`, so the loop will only run one time.

Comment: @Nishant My apologies-didn't indent enough. Well, I have another main function that calls this particular one, and whenever I type a string with digits, the main function always outputs the correct result, and that's really all that is required.

Comment: @JohnGordon So the return command has a built-in "break" effect? I see.

Comment: `return` exits the function altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question: if you `return` from a function, you don't need to also `break` out of any loops executing in that function.  They will terminate fine when the function returns.

Answer (score 2):

I think u should change code into this

```
i=0
while i < len(w):
    if w[i].isdigit():
        return True
    i+=1
return False
```

because your function only check first character is digit or not

Answer (score 0):

You are right to be concerned. Your while loop would in fact become an infinite loop if there was no "break" statement included, which would prevent the function from functioning as intended. Depending on whether or not the first character is a digit, the loop will either return True or False at the beginning. The function will have returned a value by now, therefore the "i+=1" statement will never be reached.

```
def check_digit_placement(w):
    if w.isalpha():
        return True
    else:
        i = 0
        while i < len(w):
            if w[i].isdigit():
                return True
            else:
                i += 1
        return False
```

Comment: AI generated responses are not allowed.